# Save entire table to database using Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I have a query. I have a database table with name and id as columns in it. It has 22 rows in that table with information.

Now, I get this data and display at the UI. User can add new row, delete any row and save the table.

Once user clicks save, I want the entire table to replace the already present table. This is performed via a stored procedure.

Entire database table is erased first and new entry is saved.

However sometimes it so happens that if I add 3-4 rows and save it, the database gets deleted but new rows of 22 + newly added 3 rows don't get updated in the table.

Can someone tell me an easy way to replace the table?

PS. There is no unique id in the table. So I can't update the rows. I just have to delete entire thing and save the new table rows.

Stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [DATABASE1].[sp_usertable]
    (@in_params AS XML)
AS
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM dbo.usertable;

    SELECT
        T.x.value('./Name[1]','varchar(25)') as [Name] ,
        T.x.value('./ID[1]','varchar(6)') as [ID] ,
    INTO
        #Temp
    FROM
        @in_params.nodes('/ArrayOfData/Data') as T(x);

    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[usertable] (Name, ID)
            SELECT Name, ID 
            FROM #Temp T

    COMMIT TRANSACTION

    DROP TABLE #Temp;
END
```

Comment: is this microsoft sql server or [mysql](http://www.mysql.com/)?

Comment: @JeffPuckettII- microsoft sql server.

Comment: @patrick what is the reason you are deleting entire table??  why now insert/update/delete rows in the table

Comment: @I cant insert bcos it wil jus add duplicate of the present table. cant use update bcoz there is no unique column here. tats y deleting and saving whole thing

Comment: It would help if you put the stored procedure code here for us to see.

Comment: @PradeepKumar- updated question with the store procedure i use

Comment: How many users do you have? If you have two users caching the same table in the UI, and one writes after the other one, that last person will see his version and the first one will lose theirs. You really need to isolate what steps are causing this. With reagrds to your SP, you should load the XML into the temp table then delete and insert inside a transaction - that's the point of a transaction.

Comment: *There is no unique id in the table* - that's your **first** problem - every table **ought to have** a primary key!

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could omit the use of temporary table and delete then select into your permanent table directly:

```
 USE [DATABASE1]
 GO

 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
 GO
 SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
 GO


ALTER PROCEDURE [DATABASE1].[sp_usertable]

(
 @in_params AS XML
 )
 AS
 BEGIN

  DROP TABLE dbo.usertable;

  select
  T.x.value('./Name[1]','varchar(25)') as [Name] ,
  T.x.value('./ID[1]','varchar(6)') as [ID] ,
  into  [dbo].[usertable]
  from @in_params.nodes('/ArrayOfData/Data') as T(x);


  END
```

Answer (score 1):

Check for #temp existence and drop before select

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TEMP') is not null 
    BEGIN
        DROP  TABLE #TEMP
    END
```

And change the name of #temp to something unique to this sp eg:-#utcreate - I'm guessing #temp is common usage. You might also want to consider adding some error trapping.